# Python doesn't run a file with a certain character on it's path

Tags: python

So I have a file on a folder with this absolute path:

E:\UFES\4º Semestre\Teoria dos Grafos\Trabalhos

Whenever I try to run it I get this error on the terminal:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'e:\\UFES\\4 Semestre\\Teoria dos Grafos\\Trabalhos\\main.py'
```

You can see it's ignoring the 'º' character in the path mentioned in the error, and if I remove it from the folder name the script runs whithout any issue. Is there a reason fro python to be ignoring that charater in the file path? And how could I make sure it isn't ignored?

Comment: Exactly HOW are you trying to run it, and where do you see that error?  Python 2 or Python3?  Names with Unicode characters are treated differently.

Comment: Show us exactly how you are running this code.  Are you doing it from the command line, or an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: It's almost certainly your shell not being able to handle Unicode correctly. Python never even sees that character

Comment: I'm using Python 3, and trying to debug the current active file in VS Code.